# Given an increasing function, need to construct a continuous increasing function equivalent to given function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given an increasing function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, we can define $$F(x)=\int_x^{x+1} f(t)dt,$$
which is continuous, increasing function satisfying $$f(x)\leq F(x)\leq f(x+1).$$

Question) For such $f$ can we construct a continuous increasing function $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that for all $x\in [0,\infty),$
$$c_1 f(x)\leq g(x) \leq c_2 f(x),$$
for some positive constant $c_1,c_2?$

Comment: An obvious necessary and equivalent condition for existence of $g$ is that $f(x+)/f(x-)$ is bounded above. But what is the role of $F$ in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the integer-part function, let
$$f(x) = x ^ {\lfloor x \rfloor +1}$$

Then there is no $g$ satisfying the given condition for this $f$.

For any such $g$, let $b = \lfloor c_2/c_1 \rfloor +2$. Then
\begin{align}
b-1<x<b \implies & g(x) \le c_2 x^b\\
b<x<b+1 \implies & g(x) \ge c_1x^{b+1}
\end{align}

By the continuity of $g$, $g(b)$ must satisfy both of those inequalities, so
$$c_2 b^b \ge g(b) 
\ge c_1 b^{b+1}$$
$$\frac{c_2}{c_1}\ge b$$
which is impossible.